# Java Socket connection "crashes" after reconnect

Tags: java, android, sockets, connection

I want to create a socket connection between my server and my client. My client should reconnect, after the connection timed out. For this, I try every 3 seconds to connect with my socket. And this works. But then, when I want to start reading, but then I get the error "socket closed". What could be the mistake?

Here is the error log (It's on pastebin, it doesn't formate here right):

http://pastebin.com/2t8zAvcx

But I try to get the IP from the socket before I start reading and this works...

Here is my reconnect method:

```
public void reconnect(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                try{
                    socket.close();
                    socket = null;
                }catch (IOException e) {

                }
                socket = new Socket(BackgroundService.HOSTNAME, BackgroundService.PORT);
                connected = true;
                DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                output.writeUTF(username);
                output.flush();
            }catch(UnknownHostException e){
                connected = false;
            }catch(IOException e){
                connected = false;
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Here I wait for an input:

```
public Notification waitForNotification(){
    try{
        if(!(connected))return null;
        DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        String input;
        Log.e("Before Input", socket.getInetAddress()+"");
        while((input = inputStream.readUTF()) != null){
            Notification notification = new Notification(input);
            return notification;
        }
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Lost Connection3", "ERROR");
        connected = false;
        return null;
    }
}
```

And here I manage it:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.e("HII", "HII");

    username = getDataFromStorage.loginData(getApplicationContext())[0];
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ConnectionService connectionService = new ConnectionService(username);
            while (true) {
                if(!(connectionService.getConnectionState())){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                        connectionService.reconnect();
                        continue;
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                Notification notification = connectionService.waitForNotification();
                if(notification == null){
                    continue;
                }
                processStartNotification(notification);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

And here I start the connection:

```
public ConnectionService(String username){
    this.username = username;
    try{
        socket = new Socket(BackgroundService.HOSTNAME, BackgroundService.PORT);
        connected = true;
        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        output.writeUTF(username);
        output.flush();
    }catch(UnknownHostException e){
        connected = false;
    }catch(IOException e){
        connected = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code and the error log here as text.

Comment: Please turn to the help center to understand how to ask "code not working" questions. We can*t help you with code that you aren't showing to us.

Comment: @greenapps I've edited it.

Comment: @GhostCat Now better? :-)

Comment: Yep. First observation: you got an empty catch block in your Runnable and your Service class. Not a good idea. Never: at least print the exception message.

Comment: Post the relevant parts of the logcat here. And mention what the errors and exeptions are here. Just copy/paste. For everybody this goes ok.

Comment: `Here is my reconnect method:`. On two places you create sockets and send the username. Not a good idea. Rename `reconnect` to `connect` and do away with the other where you create a socket. Do all in connect(). You can wait there too before retrying. Makes your code so much easier.

Comment: I see now that you start the (re)connect thread from another thread. Bad idea. Because you never know when they finish. And there is your problem!  You should have only one thread which does the connection. Put all code in one run().

Comment: You could also make reconnect() a function without it creating a new thread of course.